# Hand craft / deeply configure TLS Client Hello message using OkHttp client

Tags: java, ssl, okhttp

I would like to manually craft TLS Client Hello message or at least specify next values using OkHttp Client:

1. TLS versions
2. Ciphers
3. Extensions
4. EllipticCurves
5. EllipticCurves Point Formats

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

See https://square.github.io/okhttp/https/ for configuring TLS version, Ciphers.

```
ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
    .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
    .cipherSuites(
          CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
          CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
          CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256)
    .build();

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec))
    .build();
```

For the rest you will need to provide your own sslSocketFactory

https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/-builder/ssl-socket-factory/

And then configure that specifically using JSSE, BouncyCastle or Conscrypt APIs.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Yuri. The problem with `.cipherSuites` and `.tlsVersions` is that okhttp will still reorder them (alphabetize) and exclude ones that are not supported. So, not fully controlled from my side. I'm currently looking into making custom SSLSocketFactory. Do you know which SSLSocketFactory does okhttp use? And, if it's possible to extend theirs SSLSocketFactory instead of writing own one? Is it inside `Platform` class?

Comment: OkHttp doesn't alphabetise the ciphers.  Unfortunately it does use the SSL Socket default ordering over the ordering you specify - see https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/6390

But also modern JDKs now prefer the server ordering anyway.

Comment: See here for supported providers https://square.github.io/okhttp/security_providers/

All are generally through the JSSE API, but with usage of extensions to configure advanced features.  The Platform API is not a supported public API and changes between versions so avoid depending on it..